# My Broadcast Receiver doesn't receive for intents

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an app and i need another external application with a broadcast receiver only. Here is my code:

app1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.blabla.myaction");
intent.putExtra("extra", "test");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

---

app2 (The one with the receiver):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.test" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<receiver
    android:name=".myReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.blabla.myaction" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</manifest>
```

---

```
public class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context mContext;

public static final String ACTION = "com.blabla.myaction";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;

    if (ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.e("lala", "received");

        String extra = intent.getStringExtra("extra");

        if (packageName != null) {
            Log.e("lala", extra);
        }
    }
}
```

With this, i doesn't get the "received" log nor the extra. Why?

Comment: Show the portions of your classes that include the class definition -- you "receiver" does extend BroadcastReceiver , right?  And what starts the second (receiving) app?

Comment: my second application is not an "application". is just a package with a broadcastreeiver only and no activities! i tought this is possible. isn't it?

Comment: Look! I'm extending broadcast receiver!

Comment: and in the app1 I'm sending broadcast through a simple onclick button. And it start as i put some logs and i know for sure the broadcast is sent... so the broadcast is not receiving but why?

Comment: @iGio90 : because both is different application so try after setting `android:exported="true"` for `receiver`

Comment: Your receiving application has to have been started at least once ... I understand that as of Android 3.1 the Android system excludes all receiver from receiving intents by default if the corresponding application has never been started by the user or if the user explicitly stopped the application via the Android menu

Comment: @ErstwhileIII do you think i can do this with a dummy service that calls stopSelf(); immediatly after create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "recieving application has to have been started at least once.

You may want to review https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html.